# ElasticSearch 5.x should query vs filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, booleanquery

I have a problem with results come from an ES query. Filtering a query gives some confusing results, and I don't know how to overcome of it.
So:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
            {
                "multi_match":
                {
                    "query":"searchquery",
                    "operator":"and",
                    "fields":["Name", "Description", "Text"]
                }
            },
            {
                "bool":{
                    "must": [
                        {"terms": {"Id": [1, 2]}},
                        {"term": {"_type": "Project"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I want here is: get all records whose Name, or Description, or Text is match the query OR all Projects (it's a _type in the mapping), whose Id 1, or 2.
The results seems exactly what I expected, I got eg: 5 hits, 2 Contact _type, 1 Project matches "searchquery" and 2 projects with Id 1, or 2. Good!

But I have some authorization, so not all users access all Modules (Projects have another field eg: ModuleId).

So I want to restrict the results to specific ModuleIds:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
            {
                "multi_match":
                {
                    "query":"searchquery",
                    "operator":"and",
                    "fields":["Name", "Description", "Text"]
                }
            },
            {
                "bool":{
                    "must": [
                        {"terms": {"Id": [1, 2]}},
                        {"term": {"_type": "Project"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {"terms": {"ModuleId": [9, 5]}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And boom! In the result I got **all**, whose match the above query **and** all Projects with ModuleId 9, or 5. What I want is to narrow the results not broaden them. I've tried many combinations with should, must, filter(bool filter as well). I've also try post_filter which "magically" gives me the expected result, but I have some aggregations as well (not in this example), sot it is not an option.

Comment: the filter by Module is 'must' in your case but `should` clause is optional. Then you get all docs that have module 9 or 5 and if a doc meets any of `should` clauses its rank is higher

Comment: Yep, that's what i thought. I have a "solution", give the query a must_not, with all ModuleId which the User cannot access. But... come on.  I can't believe this is an intended behaviour, to narrow a result set in ES.

Answer (score 2):

```
minimum_should_match: 1
```

in the outer bool query did the job well, and works like a charm.

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
            {
                "multi_match":
                {
                    "query":"searchquery",
                    "operator":"and",
                    "fields":["Name", "Description", "Text"]
                }
            },
            {
                "bool":{
                    "must": [
                        {"terms": {"Id": [1, 2]}},
                        {"term": {"_type": "Project"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {"terms": {"ModuleId": [9, 5]}}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```